# Natural Language date and time parser for java

Tags: java, datetime, parsing, nlp

I am working on a Natural Language parser which examines a sentence in english and extracts some information like name, date etc.

for example: "*Lets meet next tuesday at 5 PM at the beach.*"

So the output will be something like : "*Lets meet 15/09/2009 at 1700 hr at the beach*"

So basically, what i want to know is that **is there any framework or library available for JAVA to do these kind of operations like parsing dates from a sentence and give a output with some specified format.**

Regards,
Pranav

---

Thanks for the replies. I have looked on few NLPs like [LingPipe](http://alias-i.com/lingpipe/index.html), OpenPL, [Stanford NLP](http://nlp.stanford.edu/index.shtml). I wanted to ask do they hav anything for date parsing for java.

Comment: FYI, a later duplicate of this question, [Generic Date Parsing Library from unstructured text](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14824782/642706)

Comment: This one https://github.com/zoho/hawking can solve your problem

Answer (score 24):

[Natty](http://natty.joestelmach.com/) is a really good replacement for JChronic.

Comment: I swear Natty handles pretty much everything. For example, `2 wednesdays from now` can't be parsed by any other solution I've found. +1

Comment: I have a system where I'm being fed strings from which I need to (on a best guess basis) remove URLs, anything which might be HTML and anything which might be a date - I've found Natty is excellent for the latter, but I've built exceptions for April, May and June, which are valid girls' names.

Comment: Seems Natty has a problem with conflicting formats. Try `15/12/2004`. It considers it as `today 15th hour`.

Comment: nice you can even try out the parser in an online demo here: http://natty.joestelmach.com/try.jsp#

Answer (score 3):

You can use [JChronic](https://github.com/samtingleff/jchronic), the Java port of [Chronic](http://chronic.rubyforge.org/).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [jchronic](https://github.com/samtingleff/jchronic)? However, I doubt any library could directly work with sentences: you'd have to extract sentence fragments and feeding them to a NLP date parsing framework yourself, perhaps on a trial-n-error basis (larger and larger fragments until the framework throws an error).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's any framework out there that does that out of the box. What you can do is create a set of regular expressions to match those patterns.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using [UIMA](http://uima.apache.org/) with [OpenNLP](http://opennlp.sourceforge.net/projects.html) connectors and same hand made regexp rules.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a NLP script in Python's NLTK and fed the results to Ruby's [chronic](https://github.com/hpoydar/chronic_duration/issues/31#issuecomment-42078264).

Answer (score 0):

For my use case, I had more luck with [chrono-java](https://github.com/wanasit/chrono-java) - sadly it looks stale and is not available in any Maven repository (also not via https://jitpack.io/ since the build is broken), so you have to fix and build it for yourself.

However, checking out the code and fixing a dependency (`maven-javadoc-plugin` was missing groupId and I updated the version), allowed me to build and run a simple example successfully:

```
List<ParsedResult> results = Chrono.Parse("Datum  Freitag, 08.04. bis einschl. Sonntag 10.04.2016");
    results.forEach(result -> System.out.println(result));
```

resulted in 2 Dates being extracted:

```
ParsedResult: " 08.04" > 04/08/2018 12:00
ParsedResult: "10.04.2016" > 04/10/2016 12:00
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty old question bur [PrettyTime::NLP](https://www.ocpsoft.org/prettytime/nlp/) is another option to try