# Intelligent date / time parser for Java

Tags: java, datetime

Is there some intelligent date / time parser library for Java? By intelligent I mean, that I don't need to specify the date / time format. The API should be similar to this:

```
Calendar cal = DateTimeParser.parse("01/06/10 14:55");
cal = DateTimeParser.parse("1 Jan 2009"); // assumes 00:00 time
cal = DateTimeParser.parse("1.2.2010");
cal = DateTimeParser.parse("kygyutrtf"); // throws exception
```

**UPDATE**:

```
// I'm telling the parser: "If unsure, assume US date format"
cal = DateTimeParser.parse("01/02/03", new Locale("en-us"));
```

Comment: Similar question to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3850784/recognise-an-arbitrary-date-string

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parse any date in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389348/parse-any-date-in-java)

Comment: This one https://github.com/zoho/hawking can solve your problem

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[JodaTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) is excellent for manipulating date objects (e.g. date.plusDays(10))

...but [***JChronic***](https://github.com/samtingleff/jchronic) is what you want for natural language date parsing, e.g.

```
Chronic.parse("now")
Chronic.parse("tomorrow 15:00")
Chronic.parse("14/2/2001")
Chronic.parse("yesterday")
Chronic.parse("20 Jan 2010")
```

Your question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3850784/recognise-an-arbitrary-date-string) one.

Comment: "Natural language date parsing" != "format-guessing date parsing"

Comment: No - but it's still useful in the context of the question.

Answer (score 3):

No, there is not. What it should return on "01/02/03"? 1 Jan 2003, 3 Feb 2001, or 2 Mar 2001?

Comment: @fhucho `10/10/10` is 2010 Oct 10 without considering the locale if it treated as day/month/year in any combination. What the parser should do for `08/09`? It is 8/Sep/current year for en-us, or Sep/2008 or Aug/2009 or it causes parsing error?

Comment: @khachik oh, you're right, I'll edit the question to 01/02/03. As for 08/09 - it should return one of the 3 options and somehow indicate that it is unsure about the result. Ideally it should behave similarly to a human...

Comment: @fhucho Ok, let's move forward. How it should indicate that it is unsure about the result, and what the code calling it should do in that case?

Comment: @khachik One option is `Parser p = new Parser(); p.parse("08/09"); p.getCertainity();`. Or `parse(...)` could return some object containing certainity.

Comment: @khachik In my case, the calling code would display something like "Error obtaining last update time", or simply do nothing, because probability of this is almost zero (in my case).

Comment: @fhucho What does the caller code do, when it got a `Certainity` object which represents one or more problems found? Your are trying to prove that is possible to make such a parser. Yes, it is possible. Such a parser can be useful for particular cases, but not in general. So if `JChronic` or anything else fits your requirements, you can use it. I have made one on Python, but it was very specific, fit my requirements, and I have met the same question a long time ago.

Answer (score 2):

Curious that you want to call that *intelligent*, just consider these:

- Is your `1.2.2010` the same as mine?
- What happens if the code is run on different time zones with varying locales?
- Should it follow some [well established](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard or invent its own entirely?

The answer to your question is *no*.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really going to be possible, or at least reliable enough.

For example, what date does the string `10/10/10` represent?

Comment: I don't need 100% reliability. For cases like this, the parse function may have locale or language as an optional argument.

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking for an intelligent date/time Parser then, check this one
https://github.com/zoho/hawking. Devolped by ZOHO ZIA Team.

Hawking Parser is a Java-based NLP parser for parsing date and time information. The most popular parsers out there like Heidel Time, SuTime, and Natty Date time parser are distinctly rule-based. As such, they often tend to struggle with parsing date/time information where more complex factors like context, tense, multiple values, and more need to be considered.

With this in mind, Hawking Parser is designed to address a lot of these challenges and has many distinct advantages over other available date/time parsers.

It's a open source Library under GPL v3 and the best one. To know why it's best, check out this blog that explains in detail : https://www.zoho.com/blog/general/zias-nlp-based-hawking-date-time-parser-is-now-open-source.html

P.S: I'm one of the developers of this project

Answer (score 1):

### *java.time*

You can build a parser using `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` that can take care of case-insensitive parsing, optional patterns (specified inside square brackets), defaulting the missing fields (e.g. `HOUR_OF_DAY`) etc.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder;
import java.time.format.DateTimeParseException;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoField;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final DateTimeFormatter parser = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                    .parseCaseInsensitive() // parse in case-insensitive manner                                     
                    .appendPattern("[M/d/uu[ H:m]][d MMM u][M.d.u][E MMM d, u]")
                    .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0)
                    .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.MINUTE_OF_HOUR, 0)
                    .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH);
        
        // Test
        Stream.of(
                    "Thu Apr 1, 2021",
                    "THU Apr 1, 2021",
                    "01/06/10",
                    "1 Jan 2009",
                    "1.2.2010",
                    "asdf"
                ).forEach(s -> {
                    try {
                        System.out.println(LocalDateTime.parse(s, parser));
                    } catch(DateTimeParseException e) {
                        System.out.println("\"" + s + "\"" + " could not be parsed. Error: " + e.getMessage());
                    }
                });     
    }   
}
```

**Output:**

```
2021-04-01T00:00
2021-04-01T00:00
2010-01-06T00:00
2009-01-01T00:00
2010-01-02T00:00
"asdf" could not be parsed. Error: Text 'asdf' could not be parsed, unparsed text found at index 0
```

Learn more about the modern date-time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [org.pojava](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.pojava/datetime/3.0.2). This library smart enough to detect time format

```
import org.pojava.datetime.DateTime;
import java.util.Date;

public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String input1 = "6-Jan-69";
        String input2 = "10 Apr 85 12:34:15";
        String input3 = "7/Mar/77";

        Date date1 = DateTime.parse(input1).toDate();
        Date date2 = DateTime.parse(input2).toDate();
        Date date3 = DateTime.parse(input3).toDate();

        System.out.println(date1);
        System.out.println(date2);
        System.out.println(date3);
    }
}
```

Output

```
Mon Jan 06 00:00:00 ICT 1969
Wed Apr 10 12:34:15 ICT 1985
Mon Mar 07 00:00:00 ICT 1977
```