# Get year format from a given Date format

Tags: java, date, format

I have a localized date format. I want to retrieve just the year format in Java.

So if I am given mmddyyyy I would like to extract yyyy.
if I am given mmddyy, i would like to extract yy.

I cannot find a way to get that info using SimpleDateFormat, Date, Calendar etc. classes.

Comment: What would be the year in the date string "01/02/03"? See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15010210/155813) and [that](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4216191/155813).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's important to note that the concept of a "year format" only really applies to `SimpleDateFormat`. (In the default JDK, anyway.) More specifically, `SimpleDateFormat` is the only `DateFormat` implementation provided by the JDK that uses the concept of a "format string" that you can pull out a year format from; the other implementations use more opaque mappings from a `Date` to a `String`. For this reason, what you're asking for is only well-defined on the `SimpleDateFormat` class (again, among the `DateFormat` implementations available in the stock JDK).

If you're working with a `SimpleDateFormat`, though, you can just pull the year format out with regular expressions:

```
SimpleDateFormat df=(something);
final Pattern YEAR_PATTERN=Pattern.compile("^(?:[^y']+|'(?:[^']|'')*')*(y+)");
Matcher m=YEAR_PATTERN.matcher(df.toPattern());
String yearFormat=m.find() ? m.group(1) : null;
// If yearFormat!=null, then it contains the FIRST year format. Otherwise, there is no year format in this SimpleDateFormat.
```

The regular expression looks so strange because it has to ignore any y's that happen in "fancy" quoted parts of the date format string, like `"'Today''s date is 'yyyy-MM-dd"`. Per the comment in the code above, note that this only pulls out the *first* year format. If you need to pull out multiple formats, you'll just need to use the `Matcher` a little differently:

```
SimpleDateFormat df=(something);
final Pattern YEAR_PATTERN=Pattern.compile("\\G(?:[^y']+|'(?:[^']|'')*')*(y+)");
Matcher m=YEAR_PATTERN.matcher(df.toPattern());
int count=0;
while(m.find()) {
    String yearFormat=m.group(1);
    // Here, yearFormat contains the count-th year format
    count = count+1;
}
```

Comment: I should always get a SimpleDateFormat. So this is the code I wrote

Comment: SimpleDateFormat df= new SimpleDateFormat("mmddyyyy");
final Pattern YEAR_PATTERN=Pattern.compile("y+");
MatchResult m=YEAR_PATTERN.matcher(df.toPattern()).toMatchResult();
String yearFormat;
if(m!=null)
 yearFormat = m.group();
else 
        yearFormat = "empty";
System.out.println("year pattern is =====>"+yearFormat);

Comment: I get Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match found

Comment: Sorry about that. Try the updated code. Devil's in the details, as usual. :P

Comment: Thank you for such a prompt reply