# Extracting dates using Java by matching date format from string

Tags: java, regex, date, date-format, simpledateformat

Is anybody aware of a third-party package that directly finds portions of an input string that match a Java DateFormat?  In other words, that converts a DateFormat  to a regular expression?

E.g., it might convert;

```
DateFromat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy")
```

to something like `"(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\\/(0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[01])\\/([0-9]{4})"` so that you would have seamless methods available like (fantasy code):

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");

DateMatcher dm = df.dateMatcher(inputString);

while (dfm.findDate()) {
#dostuff
}; // or 

if (dfm.matchesDate()) #dosomething
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3850784/recognise-an-arbitrary-date-string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SimpleDateFormat#toPattern` gets the pattern `String` of your `SimpleDateFormat` instance!  So instantiate a `SimpleDateFormat` with the constructor of your choice and use `toPattern` to extract the pattern `String`.

Answer (score 1):

yes this magic parser code is available in joda-time package. Check the implementation of DateTimeParser there.

Check classes InternalParserDateTimeParser, DateTimeParserBucket to understand how jodatime extracts date as given pattern from the input line.